# how to filter the date in angular material table

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

[image]when i enter the date in filter text box the result is filtering for month but for date if I enter date as 11 then columns filter is showing filter data of 12.
component.ts code for filtering

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

component.html code for date filtering

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="deliveryDate">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Delivery Date MM-DD-YYYY </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deliveryDate  | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: A plunkr with a [mcve] would be really useful to see what happens.

Comment: I have also tried this ,<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deliveryDate  | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}} </mat-cell> . but it is giving date +1,means if i filter 03-11 then result is 03-12